# Batch command: if IF contains .pdf

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to make batch file for printing all PDF files in folder.

1. I made `list.txt` which contains all files in folder (with `dir /x`).
2. Then I use all lines of the txt file and find "short filenames" in line (for `/F "tokens=4" ...` ; e.g. `12345678.pdf`; `list.txt`).
3. Send this file for printing ( `AcroRd32.exe" /n /t "%1"` ) and repeat #2.

The problem is that it takes all lines (also not PDF). Is any possibilities how to find part of variable and then use `IF` function?
Something like this:

```
IF "%1" == "*.pdf" echo print
```

Answer (score 2):

Your existing code simply needs to use `dir /x *.pdf`.

But I would replace your entire code with something like the following:

```
for %%F in (*.pdf) do start "" AcroRd32.exe /n /t "%%~snxF"
```