# Windows Scripting - Monitor network folder for files (PDF) and print/delete them

Tags: windows, networking, batch-file, printing

I would like to create a scheduled task to run every 5 minutes or so that will get the contents of a network share, print any PDF files, and delete those files once they have been printed.

The tricky part is automating the process - how do we accomplish this without having to approve a dialog box every time?  The printer is also a network printer (TCP/IP port) rather than LPT or COM or USB.

The script will be running on a machine whose default printer is the printer where these jobs need to be sent.

Comment: What program are you using to print them?

Comment: what have you tried? what is your question? I see two tasks here: monitor a folder for new content; and unattended printing of pdf files. Google a bit and you'll find many pointers to get you started on both tasks.

Comment: This [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428222/batch-command-if-if-contains-pdf) might help if you're using Acrobat Reader.

Comment: [How to print PDF files from a command line to a Windows printer](http://www.brooksnet.com/content/how-print-pdf-files-command-line-windows-printer), [more links](http://www.google.com/search?q=command+line+print+pdf+windows)

Answer (score 0):

This batch framework is something you can schedule to print the PDF files once you find a method to print them.  `"%%a"` is the quoted path\filename of each PDF file.

Just replace the indented line with the command and "%%a" and maybe the printer ipaddress or name or the command might use the default printer - it depends on the tool being used to print the files.

```
@echo off
for %%a in ("c:\folder\*.pdf") do (
   "print command for pdf files.exe" use this to refer to each pdf file ->> "%%a"
)
```